# Grails CXF plugin Webservice

Tags: web-services, hibernate, grails, merge

I was wondering what is the best way to handle a request for an update on an existing entity (e.g. a Person) when receiving the request as a webservice request.

In my project I have a Person domain class and I would like to expose CRUD operations as webservice operation through the CXF plugin. So I make a PersonService, and expose the methods with

```
static expose = ['cxfjax']
```

Then I have the update method:

```
@WebResult(name = "person")
@WebMethod(operationName = "update")
Person update(@WebParam(name="person")Person person) {
  println "Updating $person"
  return person.save()
}
```

In the service I get a fine Person object, but even if it has an id of an existing person, a new person is created, and the id is changed to reflect this.

SO... how do I get the person I receive "merged" into the Hibernate session, so that Grails will recognise it as an existing Person?

Kind regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

maybe...

```
@WebResult(name = "person")
@WebMethod(operationName = "update")
Person update(@WebParam(name="person")Person person) {

  println "Updating $person"
  def p = Person.get(person.id)
  if ( p ) {
     // what ever your merge logic is...
  } else {
     return person.save()
  }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that somehow you could kind of re-attach the incoming Person to a Hibernate session, based on the ID. Right now, I'm actually doing like you suggest: Person p = new Person(); p.properties = incomingPerson.properties; p.save();

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but does [attach()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html) work? ie

```
@WebResult(name = "person")
@WebMethod(operationName = "update")
Person update(@WebParam(name="person")Person person) {
  println "Updating $person"
  person.attach();
  return person.save()
}
```

I think that is the point of the method.